# Stripe Payment Links with Customer Id

Tags: stripe-payments

I am currently building an application where we want to user Stripe Payment links rather then building our own version of UI to support the same functionality. However I notice that Stripe Payment Links create a new customer every single time. Is there a way to attach my customer id to the payment link so that a new customer is not created when they attempt to buy more then one product? I would prefer not to have to have a single user have multiple customer ids inside of my database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Payment Links](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links) are not specific to a Customer record.  The documentation does include [examples](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#more-payment-links-tasks) of how you might append data to them to aid in reconciling payments to a specific individual.

If you want to make use of the Stripe hosted UI while still assigning specific Customer records then I would recommend making use of [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/how-checkout-works).

Comment: Any updates on this, seems ridiculous that they don't support existing customers with their payment link!

Comment: Support: I see, I'm afraid that when using payment links, it will always create a separate customer profile. if you want to add one time products to an existing customer, you will need to create a charge using the customer's ID: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-customer 
  https://ibb.co/r2Dfzvj

Comment: You can use the `client_reference_id` to track the customer in your own system (https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/url-parameters#streamline-reconciliation-with-a-url-parameter). But Payment Links are created from the Price object and don't automatically link back to an existing customer. Checkout is still recommended for Customer specific configurations.

Comment: I wish I knew this before I built a full payment link integration! ‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

If you attach a `?customer_id=xyz` to your payment link URL, then you will receive the `xyz` back again as the `client_reference_id` in the `checkout.session.completed` event via webhook.